# JavaFX drag and drop - perform action before OS receives drag dropped

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, drag-and-drop

I am making a file encryptor that allow user to drag and drop files. At first, I implemented dragging files into the program: that worked easily. Receive the drag dropped event, encrypt the files. However, I can't get it to work the other way around: dragging files from the program into an external program (like a file explorer).
In order to do that, I need, when the drag is done, to receive an event, decrypt the files (which may take some time if the files are large), and only then let the OS actually perform the move / copy on the freshly decrypted files. I cannot decrypt the files in `onDragDetected` because, as I said, the files may be large and decryption may take some time, which would mean the user has to wait for the decryption to be complete before dropping. Also it means a lot of unnecessary work if the drop is canceled.

Is there any way to get the files to be decrypted after the drop is done? Or, if that's not possible, to get the folder in which the files were dropped and perform the copy / move manually?

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23773431/drag-and-drop-from-javafx-scene-to-windows-explorer) helps.

Comment: Does not help at all, also, I've seen it before. Thanks though.

Comment: Your other option is to handle everything inside the `Scene`. Use a `SplitPane`. One side to handle encryption. The other side to handle decryption. Implement a file explore for both sides.

Comment: That is not a valid answer because the point is to allow the user to drag any file into the program to encrypt, whether it is from a file explorer or another app. That said, it is would be very inconvinient for the user and against the purpose of drag and drop to be forced to use the app's file manager.

Comment: It was not meant to be a valid answer. I was just giving options. Have fun coding.